# Style to an ng-option

Tags: html, css, angular, angularjs, typescript

I want to style an ng-option but no matter how much I added it, the default style of ng-select does not change.

Try it also from the file .css but I can't get results.

Barrio/Provincia
    {{barrio.nombreParametro}}
 

 Seleccione una opción válida.

Comment: You might want to post some relevant code?

Comment: You definitely want to update your question with the code you are using.  But it sounds to me like you want to look into `ViewEncapsulation` https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation